# Is there a way to concatenate two virtual columns in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a table Mailing_List using the CUSTOMERS table.  I think that makes all the columns in Mailing_List table, virtual columns

I want to concatenate the Lastname & Firstname columns into one column that reads Lastname,Firstname as Name.  Name will be the new column

```
UPDATE Mailing_List
SET || LASTNAME ',' FIRSTNAME || = Name VARCHAR2(23);
```

> Error starting at line : 12 in command -
>  UPDATE Mailing_List
> SET ||LASTNAME','FIRSTNAME|| = Name (VARCHAR2(23))
>  Error at
> Command Line : 13 Column : 5
>  Error report -
>  SQL Error:
> ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column
> specification
> 01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:

```
ALTER Mailing_List
SET ||  LASTNAME ',' FIRSTNAME || = Name (VARCHAR2(23));
```

> Error starting at line : 12 in command -
>  ALTER Mailing_List
> SET ||LASTNAME','FIRSTNAME|| = Name (VARCHAR2(23)) Error report -
> ORA-00940: invalid ALTER command
> 00940. 00000 -  "invalid ALTER command"
> *Cause:    
> *Action:

These are two different statements that I have tried, and the error messages I have received..

Comment: The concatenation operator `||` concatenates two strings, e.g. `'Hello ' || 'world'`. Your `SET || LASTNAME ',' FIRSTNAME || = Name` cannot work hence, because you have the concatenation operator placed where it makes no sense. Then, `UPDATE` updates data in the table, but you don't want to change the data. You want to add a column, which is `ALTER TABLE <table> ADD <column definition>`.

Comment: As the `ALTER TABLE` command comes in many variations, it may be a tad hard to find the right syntax, but it's worth getting used to Oracle's syntax diagrams, as they show precisely what is allowed and what not. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ALTER-TABLE.html#GUID-552E7373-BF93-477D-9DA3-B2C9386F2877

Comment: Do you want `mailing_list` to be a static snapshot of the `customers` table, that you then maintain separately as customer data changes; or do you want it to immediately reflect data changes made in the original table?

Answer (score 2):

You've created a table based on another. Something like this probably:

```
CREATE TABLE mailing_list AS SELECT * FROM customer;
```

This makes this a mere table (a copy of the other one). No virtual columns here.

Now you want to add a virtual column to the table, namely a column called `NAME` that is the concatenation of the columns `LASTNAME` and `FIRSTNAME` separated by a comma and blank. The syntax for this:

```
ALTER TABLE mailing_list ADD name AS (lastname || ', ' || firstname);
```

Comment: Hi, that is exactly how I created the table.  The syntax worked, thank you.  May I drop the Lastname FirstName columns now that the Name column has all the Data that I desired ?  Would it be warranted to set the Columns Lastname and Firstname to unused columns and make them invisible?

Comment: No, what this created is just a *virtual* column. It isn't real; it has no value; it gets its values from a computation of other columns. If you want a name column *instead* of the first and last name columns, then create a normal column instead (e.g. `ALTER TABLE mailing_list ADD name VARCHAR2(100)`), then fill this column via `UPDATE mailing_list SET name = lastname || ', ' || firstname`, then drop the original columns.

Answer (score 1):

You might want your `mailing_list` object to be a view, rather than a table. As @Thorsten said, at the moment you are creating a copy of the `customers` table, which means that it will not automatically reflect any changes made to the original table - changed names, added or removed customers, etc. A view is a stored query, so it will always reflect the data in the base table:

```
create view mailing_list as
select c.*, c.lastname || ', ' || c.firstname as name
from customers c;
```

It would be better to list out all of the columns you actually want instead of using `c.*`; even if you want them all, but you have to if you don't want to include original the `firstname` and `lastname` in the view.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f385a9954f9cbaf8357c88df396ea5bd) with the view definition above, the same thing without a table alias (following a comment), and a version with only a few columns from the original table.

Comment: what does the c stand for in the query you have provided?  That does sound like something I need

Comment: @assed - it's an alias for the table; I've just used `c` as the first letter of `customers`. You don't have to use an alias. But if you want to use `*` to represent all columns *and* you want a separate expression (like the concatenation for `name`) then you have to use `c.*` or `customers.*`, as shown in [the syntax diagrams](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__I2126854). If you don't use `*` then it's optional.

Comment: hmm well the query provided did not work.  I executed                                      
create view mailing_list as
select customers.lastname || ',' || customers.firstname FROM CUSTOMERS as name; and the error message provided read                                                                       
Error starting at line : 6 in command -
create view mailing_list as
select customers.lastname || ',' || customers.firstname FROM CUSTOMERS as name
Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: @aseed_dohkn: You have mutilated Alex's `CREATE VIEW` statement by moving the alias to an inappropriate position. Why? You want `name` to be the alias for the expression not for the table, so put it *after the expression* as Alex did.

Comment: @AlexPoole I really appreciate the guidance, I have inserted Alex's statement verbatim and have received the below error message, thank you for helping I am learning :   Error starting at line : 1 in command -
create view mailing_list as
select c.*, c.lastname || ', ' || c.firstname as name
from customers c
Error report -
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: You need to either drop the table you created earlier, or create the view with a different name. Depending on which approach you want to take - a view, or a table as Thorsten showed. You can't have both with the same name. That's what the error says.